# Ignore Where and prioritize Order By

Tags: php, mysql, sql

suppose, I have these following tables

**GUYS**

```
| ID         | 
|:-----------|
| 1          |  
| 2          | 
| 3          |
```

**SHIRT**

```
| ID         | GUYS_ID     | color        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |           1 |     red     
| 2          |           1 |     red    
| 3          |           3 |     red     
| 4          |           3 |     red      
| 5          |           3 |     red
```

I join these table using this query

```
SELECT a.id, b.color 
FROM GUYS a 
LEFT JOIN SHIRT b 
ON a.ID=b.GUYS_ID 
WHERE b.color='red' 
ORDER BY a.id ASC;
```

This only fetch GUYS that has its id ON SHIRT

wonder if its possible to fetch all GUYS including which has not relation with SHIRT?

to achieve result like this,

```
| ID         | color       |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          |         red |   
| 1          |         red |
| 2          |             |
| 3          |         red |    
| 3          |         red |    
| 3          |         red |
```

Comment: Look at 'outer joins'.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Are you really having problems with MySQL and MS SQL Server and Postgresql here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition on the color is actually a "join condition" not a "where filter" - "give me all guys and JOIN their shirts ONLY IF they are red":

```
SELECT a.id, b.color 
FROM GUYS a 
LEFT JOIN SHIRT b 
ON a.ID=b.GUYS_ID AND b.color='red' 
ORDER BY a.id ASC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ea10/2

Comment: This is no answer (=solution) rather another way to produce the same (and wrong) result ?!?

Comment: @Shnugo placing the extra condition into the outer join isn't wrong, it produces the wanted result.

Comment: @Shnugo the fiddle contains two queries, the first one is this modified one which returns the additional row `(2, NULL)` your `IS NULL` variant does.

Comment: Sorry, you're answer is perfectly OK, one should not type so fast :-) +1 from my side.

Answer (score 5):

Your WHERE is to strict:

Guys without a shirt cannot have a red shirt ;-)

```
SELECT a.id, b.color 
FROM GUYS a 
LEFT JOIN SHIRT b ON a.ID=b.GUYS_ID 
WHERE b.color IS NULL OR b.color='red'
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```